# Imap search with messageid

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail

I have a email processor java application which connects outlooks and lists folder messages and then if it decide it downloads email. I have the following problem with some emails.

Listing with following code:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new myAuthenticator());
store = session.getStore(PROTOCOL);
store.connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
inbox_unknown = store.getDefaultFolder().getFolder("INBOX_UNKNOWN");
inbox_unknown.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

messages = inbox_unknown.getMessages();
for(Message m : messages){
  Enumeration headers = m.getAllHeaders();
  while(headers.hasMoreElements()){
    Header element = (Header)headers.nextElement();
    if ("Message-ID".equals(element.getName()))
      System.err.println(element.getValue());
  }
}
```

and the result is :

```
<CAFSBYLHvG9d=MkE2Gf+q_EgoaAN8yRVHHsg5emO0w92GV6-7LA@mail.gmail.com>
<CAFSBYLGs-w4=JrgrYh_6kpiEc9NhjCsc76gXVvLWyW-=QN+kMw@mail.gmail.com>
```

However When I search with these message id with following code :

```
    messages = inbox_unknown.search(new MessageIDTerm("<CAFSBYLGs-w4=JrgrYh_6kpiEc9NhjCsc76gXVvLWyW-=QN+kMw@mail.gmail.com>"));//not found
    messages = inbox_unknown.search(new MessageIDTerm("<CAFSBYLHvG9d=MkE2Gf+q_EgoaAN8yRVHHsg5emO0w92GV6-7LA@mail.gmail.com>"));//found
```

Although message with id `<CAFSBYLHvG9d=MkE2Gf+q_EgoaAN8yRVHHsg5emO0w92GV6-7LA@mail.gmail.com>` is listed, when i search this single item i get empty return array. For other message id it returns the message object as expected. Do you have any idea what can be the problem ?
PS:This mails from same person, and this is just for example, there are many similar mails which are not found although they can be listed.

Note: using  java7, java.mail-1.4 api, ms outlook server,IMAP4 as protocol.
Note2: Added java debug output

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.5
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "outlook.abck.com.tr", port 143, isSSL false
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.abck.com.tr, user=usera, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: connection available -- size: 1
A3 EXAMINE Test
* 2 EXISTS
* 2 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] Permanent flags
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 268114] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 4] The next unique identifier value
A3 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed.
A4 SEARCH HEADER Message-ID <CAFSBYLGs-w4=JrgrYh_6kpiEc9NhjCsc76gXVvLWyW-=QN+kMw@mail.gmail.com> ALL
* SEARCH
A4 OK SEARCH completed.
A5 SEARCH HEADER Message-ID <CAFSBYLHvG9d=MkE2Gf+q_EgoaAN8yRVHHsg5emO0w92GV6-7LA@mail.gmail.com> ALL
* SEARCH 2
A5 OK SEARCH completed.
A6 FETCH 1 (BODY.PEEK[HEADER])
* 1 FETCH (BODY[HEADER] {1403}
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: from mail01.abck.com.tr (62.108.64.49) by
 EXCPRDHCS02.abck.abc (10.81.42.19) with Microsoft SMTP Server
 (TLS) id 14.3.195.1; Tue, 17 May 2016 14:31:39 +0300
Received: from mail-yw0-f170.google.com ([209.85.161.170])  by
 mail01.abck.com.tr with ESMTP/TLS/AES128-GCM-SHA256; 17 May 2016
 14:31:31 +0300
Received: by mail-yw0-f170.google.com with SMTP id x189so11988152ywe.3;
        Tue, 17 May 2016 04:31:31 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.37.14.212 with HTTP; Tue, 17 May 2016 04:31:30 -0700 (PDT)
Subject: =?utf-8?B?VEFMxLBNQVQ=?=
Thread-Topic: =?utf-8?B?VEFMxLBNQVQ=?=
Thread-Index: AQHRsC+uNbCd970/KU2ZmbAy2JPC2w==
Date: Tue, 17 May 2016 14:31:30 +0300
Message-ID:
 <CAFSBYLGs-w4=JrgrYh_6kpiEc9NhjCsc76gXVvLWyW-=QN+kMw@mail.gmail.com>
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: EXCPRDHCS02.abck.abc
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 0
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="_003_CAFSBYLGsw4JrgrYh6kpiEc9NhjCsc76gXVvLWyWQNkMwmailgmailc_"

)
A6 OK FETCH completed.
A7 FETCH 2 (BODY.PEEK[HEADER])
* 2 FETCH (BODY[HEADER] {4900}
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: from mail01.abck.com.tr (62.108.64.49) by
 EXCPRDHCS01.abck.abc (10.81.42.18) with Microsoft SMTP Server
 (TLS) id 14.3.279.2; Wed, 25 May 2016 10:30:08 +0300
IronPort-PHdr: =?us-ascii?q?9a23=3AVhJs6B+zz3F7Iv9uRHKM819IXTAuvvDOBiVQ1KB7?=
 =?us-ascii?q?0eIcTK2v8tzYMVDF4r011RmSDdSdt6gP0rCN+4nbGkU+or+5+EgYd5JNUxJXwe?=
 =?us-ascii?q?43pCcHRPC/NEvgMfTxZDY7FskRHHVs/nW8LFQHUJ2mPw6anHS+4HYoFwnlMkIt?=
 =?us-ascii?q?f6KuSt+U0578jrrps7ToICx2xxOFKYtoKxu3qQiD/uI3uqBFbpgL9x3Sv3FTcP?=
 =?us-ascii?q?5Xz247bXianhL7+9vitMU7q3cYk7sb+sVBSaT3ebgjBfwdVWx+cjN92Mq+/zTH?=
 =?us-ascii?q?TAXH3nYcVmQImxwAQy3I4xiydZr3ribg/tFg0iSBPIjVSro1ER6r6aRiQx7siS?=
 =?us-ascii?q?gGdnRxpGzTi8I2lK9bpBO/rhpXzY/SaYeOPvN4feXWetZcWXAXGo4beiBISqqg?=
 =?us-ascii?q?ZpBHT9EcN+sQl4DvrkEKpB63TSmtFubi1ndti2X10L87kq5pRQzK1UopA9sVmH?=
 =?us-ascii?q?rVqtzzL60bV+Pzx67NiynZObcexT756Y3BbjgvoPeFW6l6eMzSj0IoEkXZlAa+?=
 =?us-ascii?q?s4vgag248sVFnEW9QKI0Tv+jhmAqsQRsqyKHycIli42PjYUQnAOXvR5lyZo4cI?=
 =?us-ascii?q?XrAHVwZsSpRd4J73mX?=
X-Cloudmark-SP-Filtered: true
X-Cloudmark-SP-Result: =?us-ascii?q?v=3D2=2E1_cv=3DF5f3DvVN_c=3D1_sm=3D1_tr?=
 =?us-ascii?q?=3D0_a=3Dyrkiwgmsf1kA=3A10_a=3DxWK-KtZqUfIA=3A10?=
 =?us-ascii?q?_a=3De186Yzns-9f1=5FKZu-cIA=3A9_a=3DQEXdDO2ut3YA=3A10_a=3DOKp-?=
 =?us-ascii?q?Gz0vqPG3m8aTRrIA=3A9?=
 =?us-ascii?q?_a=3DKQqxNPgzF0kA=3A10?=
X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Filtered: true
X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Result: =?us-ascii?q?A0HiAwB/U0VXf7OhVdFbhQoGpn6HY4NNg?=
 =?us-ascii?q?xSCJYQTBCRxB4YkBzwQAQEBAQEBAQECDwEBCQsLCSEbFIIuCjkQVQIrTA0RHQE?=
 =?us-ascii?q?bHgMSAwUBAgUSAQELGAIEFQEKAREBBQEREQEYHIdyAQMXlVGPQoExPjGKBoE1g?=
 =?us-ascii?q?WqCWAWIKwoZJw1Sg1cMFwYCBhCSI4JZBY5VhwWCXYMrgWmJDIFTAY1Ijg0SHoE?=
 =?us-ascii?q?PN4QbOTKKBwEBAQ?=
X-IPAS-Result: =?us-ascii?q?A0HiAwB/U0VXf7OhVdFbhQoGpn6HY4NNgxSCJYQTBCRxB4Y?=
 =?us-ascii?q?kBzwQAQEBAQEBAQECDwEBCQsLCSEbFIIuCjkQVQIrTA0RHQEbHgMSAwUBAgUSA?=
 =?us-ascii?q?QELGAIEFQEKAREBBQEREQEYHIdyAQMXlVGPQoExPjGKBoE1gWqCWAWIKwoZJw1?=
 =?us-ascii?q?Sg1cMFwYCBhCSI4JZBY5VhwWCXYMrgWmJDIFTAY1Ijg0SHoEPN4QbOTKKBwEBA?=
 =?us-ascii?q?Q?=
Received: from mail-yw0-f179.google.com ([209.85.161.179])  by
 mail01.abck.com.tr with ESMTP/TLS/AES128-GCM-SHA256; 25 May 2016
 10:29:57 +0300
Received: by mail-yw0-f179.google.com with SMTP id o16so39498708ywd.2;
        Wed, 25 May 2016 00:29:57 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to;
        bh=w8xSZyobRcFMKx+IrtarhnHXAm9n7xJEYfaDMmptcKI=;
        b=WN8u7uLAyNhcAoB+oQ5xbsKdpV4z4BGWD6CrryDyJqq7tosj82QH3d3MQWHaqf2mBa
         AqlmCBq5w3ntokCoKrQlzdQNGecJ7AvIrc/CPFkYLeT3MK1kcY8gzDANJC/Pm5NO75td
         S/mBW9goEL1gKFwpd/DahOzIwKbT5UEz9hthcTU5JIPwJR305/boxMIP3zcu1M+WPVPY
         RhnojBbe41iCfqemB11IIvFeyRMqck6x7dDnWnejriEP2Gp8x4s2FYLz5rysEloNe0wU
         qKmmNXtsIStwJhdk8jjByMW/UsK+94t3+jr+rzbTyYndh/Hs3SbZsmDQipBG8+SHxRQu
         e/TQ==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
        h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to;
        bh=w8xSZyobRcFMKx+IrtarhnHXAm9n7xJEYfaDMmptcKI=;
        b=iXyugXgd1ER8sfK9PJXcq88MO8z2/VKl31XNf/Bp2E1BvC42ZxLsAGjeHKL6KqqzFb
         CNdHhBLnyfAnGoaa9pIK+qoC2HT69e323Rmym3w6HxQr1ot396xThXXxL22ZManrpICu
         RAPegTlsmXQ1VBqhYQjgX8NwX6FtoqtzBW9tSOnl+HTfdyv3CNNf0mAysA7jyCHwQy6j
         Nc+JK/uUZjccYkic672MiDSUa4FfwJSx0L3nyWI/CZMVDaNVW3mtp04cpgvtshLkloLn
         61bz3dlGNL1g3gIVwNFiY8SLGxFdPzRc7xJ9VJEgXoA1h2OO2QVqyEUUyivhzehbgvL5
         Bhtw==
X-Gm-Message-State: ALyK8tLPd9mwwszKuBwk9ndltkf3tyZ91virPLkoGP8PigQLffqE7vB7NVGiauqhPC9vcXsZnsU/mzB4zSTZbg==
X-Received: by 10.13.217.151 with SMTP id b145mr1363469ywe.53.1464161395972;
 Wed, 25 May 2016 00:29:55 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.37.14.212 with HTTP; Wed, 25 May 2016 00:29:55 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Wed, 25 May 2016 10:29:55 +0300
Message-ID: <CAFSBYLHvG9d=MkE2Gf+q_EgoaAN8yRVHHsg5emO0w92GV6-7LA@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?QsOcxZ5SQSBFVMSwIE1VU1RBRkEgRVTEsCBLSURFTSBUQVpNxLBOQVRJIMOWREVNRSBUQQ==?=
    =?UTF-8?B?TMSwTUFUSQ==?=
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="001a114fa43ee6ce4a0533a5a3c5"
Return-Path: abc@gmail.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: EXCPRDHCS01.abck.abc
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AVStamp-Mailbox: SMEXw]nP;1254500;0;This mail has
 been scanned by Trend Micro ScanMail for Microsoft Exchange;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 0
X-PP-Proceessed: 162a0e36-1ac8-484f-b83f-d5c2dc8a3c0b

)
A7 OK FETCH completed.
A8 CLOSE
A8 OK CLOSE completed.
DEBUG IMAP: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
A9 LOGOUT
* BYE Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 IMAP4 server signing off.
A9 OK LOGOUT completed.
DEBUG IMAP: IMAPStore connection dead
DEBUG IMAP: IMAPStore cleanup, force false
DEBUG IMAP: IMAPStore cleanup done
```

Comment: Can you turn on [JavaMail debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and post the output when running your test program?  It's probably a bug in the server; the debug output should help confirm that.  Also, if possible, upgrade to the [latest version of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) in case it will help.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have upgraded to latest version and added debug log.

Comment: Yup, that's pretty clearly a bug in the Exchange server.  Please report it to Microsoft; include the debug output.  What version of Exchange are you using?  You might want to make sure you have all the latest updates applied.  There's not much you can do with JavaMail to work around the server bug other than the **much** more expensive approach of fetching the header and comparing it yourself.  You could also try searching for subsets of the Message-ID string in case some of the special characters are confusing the server, and then do the full comparison by fetching the header and comparing.

Comment: Thank you, I will report it to microsoft and will see.

Comment: If anyone stumbles across this it'd also be good to try removing the < and > characters around the message ID.